# Merging CSV Rows with Common Data and Updating Count

Tags: python, csv, pandas, join

I have a CSV with data like the following:

**document_id | body_mention | count**

doc_01   |  Bob   | 5

doc_03   |  Sam   | 1

doc_04   |  Bob   | 1

Where `body_mention` are names parsed out from text and `count` is how many times that name appeared in a certain document (`document_id`). So, Bob appeared 5 times in doc_01.

However, I want my CSV to update so that an occurrence of Bob will simply update the previous Bob entry, so the new update looks like:

**document_id | body_mention | count**

doc_01, doc_04 | Bob  | 6

doc_03 | Sam | 1

Any ideas how I could start scripting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little awkward but you can use two defaultdicts, one to keep track of all the docs for each person and the other to keep a sum of all the values of the docs

```
import csv
import collections

name_sum = collections.defaultdict(int)
docs_for_name = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("csv1.csv") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        name_sum[row[1]] += int(row[2])
        docs_for_name[row[1]].append(row[0])

with open("outputcsv.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for key in sorted(name_sum.keys()):
        row = [", ".join(sorted(docs_for_name[key])), key, str(name_sum[key])]
        print(row)
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

You didn't post an actual csv file, just what the csv file looks like in an editor like excel, so I'm assuming your csv looks like this:

```
doc_01,Bob,5
doc_03,Sam,1
doc_04,Bob,1
```

This ends up outputting a csv file like:

```
"doc_01, doc_04",Bob,6
doc_03,Sam,1
```

[image]

The first defaultdict, `name_sum` just keeps track of the sum for all the values for each name, so it ends up looking like

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Bob': 6, 'Sam': 1})
```

And the other defaultdict to keep track of all the docs for the name, `docs_for_name` ends up looking like:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Bob': ['doc_01', 'doc_04'], 'Sam': ['doc_03']})
```

Then you have all the information you need to write each row in your new csv file

Answer (score 0):

You could read your `csv` from `pandas`, using `import pandas as pd; pd.read_csv()`. Then you data can be stored inside a `Dataframe`, like below:

```
df
Out[86]: 
  document_id body_mention  count
0      doc_01          Bob      5
1      doc_03          Sam      1
2      doc_04          Bob      1
```

After that, to achieve what you want, you can use following 2 lines of code:

```
rslt = pd.concat([df.groupby('body_mention').sum(), df.groupby('body_mention').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['document_id']))], axis=1).reset_index()
rslt.columns = ['body_mention', 'count', 'document_id']
```

---

**Explanation**:

```
In [91]: rslt = pd.concat([df.groupby('body_mention').sum(), df.groupby('body_mention').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['document_id']))], axis=1).reset_index()

In [92]: rslt
Out[92]: 
  body_mention  count              0
0          Bob      6  doc_01,doc_04
1          Sam      1         doc_03

In [93]: rslt.columns = ['body_mention', 'count', 'document_id']

In [94]: rslt
Out[94]: 
  body_mention  count    document_id
0          Bob      6  doc_01,doc_04
1          Sam      1         doc_03
```

Finallly, you can use `rslt.to_csv('rslt.csv')` to save your result dataframe to `csv`.

ps, if you want the output columns to follow the exact sequence, just use below:

```
rslt = rslt[['document_id', 'body_mention', 'count']]

rslt
Out[99]: 
     document_id body_mention  count
0  doc_01,doc_04          Bob      6
1         doc_03          Sam      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby("body_mention")['document_id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))

# body_mention
# Bob    doc_01,doc_04
# Sam           doc_03
# Name: document_id, dtype: object

df.groupby("body_mention")['count'].sum()

#body_mention
# Bob    6
# Sam    1
# Name: count, dtype: int64
```

So these two lines:

```
    dfOut= pd.concat([df.groupby("body_mention")['count'].sum(),df.groupby("body_mention")['document_id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)) ], axis=1)
    dfOut.to_csv('out.csv',sep = "|")
```

csv file:

```
body_mention|count|document_id
Bob|6|doc_01,doc_04
Sam|1|doc_03
```